# How do I execute a fabfile from my python script?

Tags: python, fabric

I have a fabfile and here are the contents:

```
[root@ip-10-10-20-82 bakery]# cat fabfile.py
from fabric.api import run
def deploy():
        run('wget -P /tmp https://s3.amazonaws.com/LinuxBakery/httpd-2.2.26-1.1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm')
        run('sudo yum localinstall /tmp/httpd-2.2.26-1.1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm')
```

I can execute the fabfile successfully when it is run from the command line like so:

```
fab -f fabfile.py -u ec2-user -i id_rsa -H 10.10.15.242 deploy
```

The problem is that it it does not work when I run it from within my Python script. This is how it is run within my script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', '/home/myhome/scripts/bakery/fabfile.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'deploy'])
```

This is the error which I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Fabfile didn't contain any commands!
Aborting.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Change fabfile.py and add these few changes.

```
@task
def deploy(): 
    ... rest of the code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local('fab -f /path/fabfile.py deploy')
```

Then run it in python

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion. I changed my fabfile.py to look like so: `[root@ip-10-10-20-82 bakery]# cat fabfile.py
from fabric.api import run
@task
def deploy():
        run('wget -P /tmp https://s3.amazonaws.com/LinuxBakery/httpd-2.2.26-1.1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm')
        run('sudo yum localinstall /tmp/httpd-2.2.26-1.1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm')
if __name__ == "__main__":
        local('fab -f /home/ralawson/scripts/bakery/fabfile.py deploy')`. However, when I run my Python script I still get the same error. Can you please explain your suggestion in more detail?